Difference between Spec $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ and $\mathbb{A}^n_k$
I am taking a informal (sort of unrigorous) introduction to Algebraic Geometry and professor teaches stuff from his mind (it seems like it is not well organized).
I was trying to make sense of the content by reading the literature, but even in the beginning course and literature differs and I can't make sure of what is going on. My question is as follows :

In the course we defined $\mathbb{A}^n_k = \text{Spec}(k[x_1,\dots,x_n])$. Notes here defines $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ as $k^n$ with Zariski topology, and I think similar is in Harthsorne. Why did we define affine space using spectrum?

Note: I asked the professor, but he said it is more general this way. I am not sure general for what purposes, since this is my first time learning. I suspect it has to do with evaluation map, but I am not sure how to proceed.
Also, it seems even in $n=1$ case, these spaces are not really the same thing, say assuming $k$ is algebraically closed. $k$ can be naturally viewed as subset of $\text{Spec}(k[x])$ but not all of it, since there is a remaining point $(0)$. Thus maybe calling them 'same thing' was incorrect.

They are "morally" the same thing – they both capture the same ideal thing, namely the space of $n$-tuples of numbers. It's something like the difference between the Dedekind real numbers and the Cauchy real numbers – when you dig into the details, they are completely different things, but you know they are both trying to capture the same idea.

I think one of the clearest motivations (after varieties, or just $k^n$) for schemes is nilpotent elements, which allows us to discuss the multiplicity of subvarieties (e.g., a point) by the space itself, as well as the tangent space or infinitesimal neighborhoods. This is achieved when we have the large generality; e.g. equivalence between the categories of affine schemes and rings. However, these cannot be understood simply without backgrounds, and I think that's one reason for the course structure (I'm actually one of the TAs).

Hartshorne refines his definition of affine space in chapter 2. It's just in chapter 1 that he's using $k^n$.
